# Audio on Mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, audio, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to apps development, so I apologize if I am asking something which may seem simple.

I am building a hybrid application using ionic. Everything was smooth until I tried to play audio. I am trying to play an HLS audio stream and some mp3 files located on a web server.

After a research on the internet and various tests using players, I used the video.js. After some tests I figured out, that the player was not responding to android versions prior to 4.4.2. ...and I haven't yet made any test on IOS.

I am realy confused on how I can play audio on a hybrid mobile application.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio feature in Ionic Framework can be implemented by using the  [Apache  Cordova Media plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova/media/media.html), and [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/).

Install the plugin by running the following ,

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

**1.Play audio file from internet**

**`html`**

```
 <button class="button" ng-click="play('http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2013.mp3')">Play from internet</button>
```

**1.play a song from the file system**

**`html`**

```
 <button class="button" ng-click="play('www/mp3/song.mp3')">Play from file system</button>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.play = function(src) {
    var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
    $cordovaMedia.play(media);
}
```

it will try to play song from **`/storage/emulated/0/www/mp3/song.mp3`**

Please refer this **[blog](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/playing-audio-android-ios-ionicframework-app/)**.You will get more idea.If you have any doubt,please let me know,thanks

Comment: Your answer is just what I wanted. Thank you so much! Do you know if the media plugin can play audio stream like HLS?  If you don't know nevermind I will try it, to see it for myself

Comment: Glad to help you.If you need any help Please let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing audio and it is essential to your app, you should think about programming an audio service (in Java). When the user navigates to another app and the system is under heavy load, the use of an audio service prevents the OS from killing your audio along with your activities.

Also, when audio playback gets into the app, you must make sure that the playback stops when a phone call arrives or the app loses the audio focus. I don't know, whether or not you can handle all of this with ionic and I also don't know your coding skills. But handling audio on Android can quickly become a very complex task. Hence I recommend a separate service, that works as an encapsulated component.

Comment: Unfortunately my coding skills in Java are not adequate for such a project.  Thanks a lot for your help and your advise!